# Create song list from expansion zipfile for oncompletionlistener

Tags: android, arraylist, android-mediaplayer, file-descriptor, zip

I have been trying to do it in different ways, but all the "lists" want int or string and I have Assetfiledescriptor stuff to work with.

How can I create a list of certain mp3 files, which are located in the activity expansionfile, that I can use for oncompletionlisteners, etc?

They all work fine individually, but I want to play them after each other.

Here are a few files that I would use:

`AssetFileDescriptor dfFn01, dfFn02, dfFn03 = null;`

`dfFn01 = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("l1r_df_l6.mp3");
dfFn02 = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("l1r_df_l7.mp3");
dfFn03 = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor("df_jp_l1r03.mp3");`

Here is the player that starts from a buttonclick:

`public void setWholeEngAudio(AssetFileDescriptor fd) throws IllegalStateException {
        try {
            stopPlayers();
            wholeTextPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            wholeTextPlayer.reset();
            wholeTextPlayer.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor(), fd.getStartOffset(), fd.getLength());
            try {
                wholeTextPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            wholeTextPlayer.start();
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
            seekBar.setMax(100);
            updateSeekBar();
            setThumbState();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }`

Thanks